# NtWaitForKeyedEvent alertable?

Tags: winapi, asynchronous, synchronization, apc

I'm using Windows keyed events for custom synchronization primitives, inspired by http://locklessinc.com/articles/keyed_events/

To support thread interruption, I've changed places were blocking calls like Sleep or WaitForSingleObject were used to their alertable versions like SleepEx and WaitForSingleObjectEx.  Then I can interrupt a wait by queueing an APC with QueueUserAPC and if the returns is WAIT_IO_COMPLETION I throw a special exception which causes all the destructors to be called and then the thread exit.  This is similar to the Linux version of pthread_cancel() which causes the stack to unwind and so stuff is cleaned up when the thread exits.

I see that NtWaitForKeyedEvent() has an Alertable parameter as well, so I'm wondering if I can do the same thing for this case, or there are caveats?  If an APC would wake this up, I also don't know what return value to look for, since NTSTATUS does not directly correspond to WIN32 return codes.  There is a STATUS_USER_APC and a STATUS_ALERTED and I don't know if it would be either of those two.  If a user APC function is not sufficient to alert the keyed event wait, what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NtWaitForKeyedEvent` with Altertable = TRUE does look like it will do what you want. That's the parameter you set with `NtWaitForSingleObject` to enable reciept of APCs as well.

You will recieve `STATUS_USER_APC` if the wait completed due to an APC being run and `STATUS_ALERTED` if `NtAlertThread` is called in connection with your thread. If all you want is a signal to stop the wait, `NtAlertThread` is sufficient.

If your exception handling mechanism does SEH unwinds you can probably throw the special exception directly from the APC routine.

Comment: This seems to work well. I use the APC since it lets me carry out the setting of some flags so I can check whether the cancellation is user-requested. One thing I'm not too sure is what to do in cases where the the wait was interrupted but the alert is different. I think the correct thing would be to resume the wait (with appropriately adjusted timeout, if that's being used), but this perhaps is a problem if there is a chance to miss an NtReleaseKeyedEvent(). Does the keyed event API account for this aspect of alerts in some manner?